# How to put down a div when the user is scrolled down for the page end?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a `<div class="more">Load more</div>` "button" (this place inside the `<div class="video-body"></div>`).
This div load the posts from database when you click for it.
The problem is, when the records is visible, you must scroll up to button if you whant get more records.
This not realy good if you whant a good user experience.
So I would like to reach, when the user scrolled down for the page end, the "button" is come down for the user for him can click it.
I tryed something like this:

```
$( ".more" ).scrollTop( 300 );
```

But the button just stick on there place, so not move.
I also tryed set the `fixed` position in css, but if I set this value, the div just has gone from the main div.
**Edit:**
You can find a demo in here:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/addvideos/type.html
For open div, press Ctrl+i.

Comment: can you post more code (html, js)?

Comment: Demo added for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like have this button "More" in fixed position you could organize differently your html so, you could create a div inside video body where push the new loaded post.

With this solution the button will be after the last post loaded.

So your HTML will be something like:

```
<div id="video-body" class="video-body ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: block; right: 31px;">
...
<div id="container-post">
    <div class="item">...
    <div class="clear">...
</div><!-- AFTER THIS DIV WE CAN ADD OUR BUTTON MORE -->

<div id="more" class="more">Továbbiak betöltése </div>
```

Now you should change a little bit the function of javascript the load the new posts.
Inside javascript:

```
function(data){
       if(data){
            $('#container-post').append(data);  //We change the target where append data
            $more.removeClass('clicked').text($text_default);
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$go_to},800);
            $start+=4;// 10 giá trị load ra
        }    
        else{
             $more.remove();
        }
  }
```

I hope this answer can help you :)

Comment: Well, I commented out css properties for example position fixed, and the button is stack in there.
The html is correct.

Comment: You have also to modify the HTML and javascript.
Now the button and the posts have the same parent div. 
If you put the posts in a separate div the button will be at the botton of this div.

Comment: I can't add this for video body, becouse when you press the ctrl+i this replace the original html.
So actualy every important content come from the video-name.php (this you get when you crtl+i).
When you get this file, you replace the orginal source.

Comment: And you gess where is the video-body?
On type.html.
Where is the other stuff?
Video-name.php

Comment: But you can't modify the video-name.php?

Comment: Yes, Ican but, I cant add a div with video-body in video-name.php, this make a little mass in the code.

Comment: I found a little lasy Solution, but thx for your answe!
If I have enough reputation, Iwill be vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a little lasy solution.
So instand of variate the div place, why not just hide it?
Something like this:

```
$( ".video" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( ".video-body" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).show();
});
$( ".video-header" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( ".video-header p" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( ".ytp-thumbnail" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( ".ytp-thumbnail" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".ytp-large-play-button" ).hide();
});
$( "body" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).show();
});



$( ".result" ).hover(function() {
    $( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( "iframe" ).click(function() {
$( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( "#player" ).click(function() {
$( ".more" ).hide();
});
$( ".video-body" ).click(function() {
$( ".more" ).show();
});
```

And a code is contain show elements, so when you click on "video-body" or hover the body element, you get the div, but when you hovered the result, div is gone, and never noing.